# New mouse cursor doesn't appear in list sudo update-alternatives --config x-cursor-theme

Tags: mouse, themes, cursor

I tried installing a new mouse cursor and put the unzipp/tarred file in the folder named `~/.icons`.

I selected the theme with gnome-tweak-tool, but it won't change properly. The default cursor doesn't change, all the rest does though. I've tried this method (and many others now) of manually adding it through `gksu gedit /usr/share/icons/default/index.theme`. I've tried it with gnome-tweak-tool, with ubuntu tweak, with gconf-editor and even `sudo update-alternatives --config x-cursor-theme`, but when I try this method my mouse cursor doesn't even appear in the list. How can I add my new mouse cursor to this list?

Comment: I've found a video on YouTube by one of the people of wepupd8 which solves this issue. I haven't tried it out yet, but when I do, I will tell. Here's [the link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a5_WGPPMKrg&feature=g-u-u)

Answer (score 7):

I believe you have to move your theme to the `/usr/share/icons` directory for it to work.

Also you have to locate the `index.theme` (or any `.theme` file) of the theme you want to install and add it to `update-alternatives` using the `--install` option.

Let's take as example the theme *ComixCursors-LH-White-Small* ( a left-handed cursor theme from the package [comixcursors-lefthanded [image: Install comixcursors-lefthanded]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/comixcursors-lefthanded)). Its `index.theme` file looks like

```
[Icon Theme]
Name = Comix Cursor LH White Small Bold
Comment = The left-handed Comix Cursors - White Small Bold
Example = default
```

but it should have an `Inherits` line equal to the directory in `/usr/share/icons` in which the theme is saved, otherwise it won't work. So add

```
Inherits = ComixCursors-LH-White-Small
```

Now tell `update-alternatives` about your new theme

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/share/icons/default/index.theme x-cursor-theme /usr/share/icons/ComixCursors-LH-White-Small/index.theme 91
```

where you should change the second last parameter to the `index.theme` of your theme. If you did this correctly

```
sudo update-alternatives --config x-cursor-theme
```

should display your new theme, and after logging out and in, your new theme should be applied.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatives available for update-alternatives need to be set up prior to use. This is normaly done by the package scripts. You can add your theme as an alternative like so:

```
update-alternatives --install /usr/share/icons/default/index.theme x-icon-theme /usr/share/icons/$YOURTHEME/cursor.theme 9999
```

or you can just link your file to /usr/share/icons/default/index.theme and forget about the alternatives system.